# C++ Direct2D ID2D1HwndRenderTarget's parent IUnknown class' _vfptr variable becomes null

Tags: c++, com, directx, direct2d

I have a Direct2D app that I am making, and I am writing a Direct2D library that makes using Direct2D easier for me as well. I'll post the exact problematic code if I need to, but my main issue is that I have an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget in the definition of one class, I extend that class with another class, in the child class I have a method that calls a method of the parent class that initializes the Render Target, and then in turn calls the load method of the child class. However, as soon as the program reaches the load content method of the child class, the __vfptr variable (I don't have a clue what that is) in the IUnknown portion of the ID2D1HwndRenderTarget is now null. The only reason I figured this out is in some other code I was getting an access violation error when using the render target to create a ID2D1Bitmap from an IWicBitmapSource. I don't understand how this happens because after initializing the Render Target, that _vfptr variable becomes null as soon as the method with the initialization code returns. Can anyone explain why this may be happening? My relevant code is below.

This code is called once to create the hwnd render target and the offscreen render target. This is in a dll project.
GameBase.cpp

```
HRESULT GameBase::Initialize(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND winHandle, struct DX2DInitOptions options)
        {
            this->mainRenderTarget = NULL;
            this->offscreenRendTarget = NULL;
            this->factory = NULL;

            HRESULT result;

            D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS factOptions;
            D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE factType;

            if(options.enableDebugging)
                factOptions.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL::D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_ERROR;
            else
                factOptions.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL::D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;

            if(options.singleThreadedApp)
                factType = D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED;
            else
                factType = D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED;

            result = D2D1CreateFactory(factType, factOptions, &this->factory);

            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugString(L"Failed to create a Direct 2D Factory!");
                return result;
            }

            this->instance = hInst;
            this->hwnd = winHandle;

            D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(options.winWidth, options.winHeight);

            this->width = options.winWidth;
            this->height = options.winHeight;

            result = factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(winHandle, size), &this->mainRenderTarget);

            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugString(L"Failed to create a render target to draw to the window with!");
                return result;
            }

            result = this->mainRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&this->offscreenRendTarget);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugString(L"Failed to create an offscreen render target from the main render target.");
                return result;
            }

            return LoadContent();
        }
```

After the call to LoadContent, at no point in time do I change the value of the mainRenderTarget.

DX2DImage.cpp

```
HRESULT DX2DImageLoader::LoadFromResource(LPCWSTR resourceName, LPCWSTR resourceType, HMODULE progModule, DX2DImage* image)
        {
            if(!this->isInit)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("You must call InitializeImageLoader before using this image loader!");
                return E_FAIL;
            }

            IWICBitmapDecoder *decoder = NULL;
            IWICBitmapFrameDecode *source = NULL;
            IWICStream *stream = NULL;
            IWICFormatConverter *converter = NULL;

            HRSRC imageResHandle = NULL;
            HGLOBAL imageResDataHandle = NULL;
            void *imageFile = NULL;
            DWORD imageFileSize = 0;

            HRESULT result;


            //Find the image.
            imageResHandle = FindResource(progModule, resourceName, resourceType);
            if(!imageResHandle)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to get a handle to the resource!");
                return E_FAIL;
            }
            //Load the data handle of the image.
            imageResDataHandle = LoadResource(progModule, imageResHandle);
            if(!imageResDataHandle)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to load the image from the module!");
                return E_FAIL;
            }
            //Lock and retrieve the image.
            imageFile = LockResource(imageResDataHandle);
            if(!imageFile)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to lock the image in the module!");
                return E_FAIL;
            }
            //Get the size of the image.
            imageFileSize = SizeofResource(progModule, imageResHandle);
            if(!imageFileSize)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to retrieve the size of the image in the module!");
                return E_FAIL;
            }
            //Create a stream that will read the image data.
            result = this->factory->CreateStream(&stream);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to create an IWICStream!");
                return result;
            }
            //Open a stream to the image.
            result = stream->InitializeFromMemory(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(imageFile), imageFileSize);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to initialize the stream!");
                return result;
            }
            //Create a decoder from the stream
            result = this->factory->CreateDecoderFromStream(stream, NULL, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, &decoder);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to create a decoder from the stream!");
                return result;
            }
            //Get the first frame from the image.
            result = decoder->GetFrame(0, &source);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to get the first frame from the decoder!");
                return result;
            }
            //Create a format converter to convert image to 32bppPBGRA
            result = this->factory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to create a format converter!");
                return result;
            }
            //Convert the image to the new format.
            result = converter->Initialize(source, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.0f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to convert the image to the correct format!");
                return result;
            }

            //Create the Direct2D Bitmap from the Wic Bitmap.
            result = this->renderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &image->bitmap);
            if(FAILED(result))
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("Failed to create a Direct 2D Bitmap from a WIC Bitmap!");
                return result;
            }

            image->width = static_cast<UINT>(image->bitmap->GetSize().width);
            image->height = static_cast<UINT>(image->bitmap->GetSize().height);

            SafeRelease(&source);
            SafeRelease(&converter);
            SafeRelease(&decoder);
            SafeRelease(&stream);

            return S_OK;
        }
```

The Access Violation exception occurs on the line

```
result = this->renderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, NULL, &image->bitmap);
```

where image->bitmap is a currently NULL (Like it's supposed to be) ID2D1Bitmap.

Here, the renderTarget variable is the same mainRenderTarget variable from GameBase.cpp above. When I debug the line, all the parents of the RenderTarget are not null, however once I get to the IUnknown interface under it all, the _vfptr thing is null. This is not the case with the converter variable, this variable, or image variable.

Comment: Seems like you've accidentally corrupted the memory of your object. We'll need code to help figure out why...

Comment: Where did you initialize the instance of DX2DImageLoader? are you sure the renderTarget is non-null before calling CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap? I don't think this is related to IUnknown.

Comment: The weird thing is, when I check the value of it using the Visual Studio Debugger, the Render Target itself is not null. When I do something like if(mainRenderTarget != NULL), this statement evaluates to true. Also, DX2DImageLoader can be used from anywhere so long as the render target and Direct 2D factory are both not null. In this specific case, it is in the client game using the library.

Comment: regarding the debugging issue, did you use the debug build? I met same problem once I try to build the release build and forgot turn back to debug build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough code to debug your code, but from what I see I suspect the call to `converter->Initialize(...)` be invalid since `MSDN` say:

```
If you do not have a predefined palette, you must first create one. Use
InitializeFromBitmap to create the palette object, then pass it in along
with your other parameters. 

dither, pIPalette, alphaThresholdPercent, and paletteTranslate are used to
mitigate color loss when converting to a reduced bit-depth format. For
conversions that do not need these settings, the following parameters values
should be used: dither set to WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, pIPalette set to NULL,
alphaThresholdPercent set to 0.0f, and paletteTranslate set to
WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom.
```

And in your code you do not provide a valid pallete(you used `NULL`) and your *paletteTranslate* is not **WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom**

Comment: The problem with that is that my code has been working perfectly and it just started doing this today for no apparent reason as far as I know. My problem is that I create the render target, and then the IUnknown's _vfptr of the render target becomes null as soon as the LoadContent function is called.

Comment: If you are making a bad call then it is irrelevant what your code used to do. You must fix this error. If it turns out not to be the problem, then lucky you.

Comment: @NkosiDean As you may already know, `_vfptr` is actually `virtual` table of the class, and it can never changed even in the code of the caller (you can't change your `virtual table` normally) unless you have a memory corruption that write something(in this case `NULL`) over it, so certainly you have a memory corruption, so if what I posted is not the case of your error, please send more code that we can debug it and possibly find your problem

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the purpose of the _vfptr now with your explanation, although I don't know what you're referring to when talking about null. If you're talking about the render target, it HAS to be null when I put it into the CreateHwndRenderTarget function, it's how DirectX initializes the COM interfaces. I set it to null in the classes constructor, like I'm supposed to for pointers in the class declaration. I never set its value to null anywhere after the call to CreateHwndRenderTarget. I agree with you though, it has to be some kind of memory corruption, I just don't where.

Comment: @NkosiDean You say in your question that `__vfptr variable in the IUnknown portion of the ID2D1HwndRenderTarget is now null`, and I say that it can't become `NULL` unless you corrupt your memory(somebody write to a memory position while it shouldn't)

Comment: Well, the Visual Studio 2012 Debugger shows it as either NULL, or it says unable to read memory. I know at least 2 or 3 times it did say null (Perhaps a bug with Visual Studio, since that should be impossible?), but now it just says unable to read its memory. I'll keep trying to figure out what may be causing this memory corruption, because all is fine until the GameBase::Initialize method calls LoadContent.

Comment: @NkosiDean Don't get me wrong, I never said it is impossible, I said it is impossible through normal code, but if you corrupt your memory you can write any value to `__vfptr` and if object released when you are using it, `__vfptr` may become invalid and `MSVC` can't read it